# Ways To Colour A Tetrahedral With 4 Different Colours

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I've been working through a text on combinatorics, and came across this question: 
[image]

Along with it's solution: 
[image]

What I don’t understand about this solution is the case where the tetrahedron is painted with 4 different colours. I agree that all tetrahedra painted with 4 colours can be oriented so that the bottom is $R$ and $G$ faces towards you. However, there are 2 things I don’t understand:

1. I agree that in this orientation, with $R$ at the bottom and $G$ towards you, $BW$ and $WB$ look different. However, how can we be sure there is no way to orient these two so that they look the same? Can someone explain why this is the case to me? I find it difficult to prove to myself that there is no way to orient these two so that they look the same, because I’m not very good at visualizing stuff - I can’t visualize how either of these will look once they are rotated.
2. How can I be sure that these are the only 2 unique arrangements? What if I placed two shapes such that blue faces forward, and white faces towards the bottom, then find that there are a bunch of unique arrangements? How would I know these arrangements are the same arrangements as the two unique arrangements with red in front and green at the bottom? Again, could you explain this for a person who’s not very good at visualizing stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ Since we have *fixed* $R$ at the bottom and $G$ towards us, any rotation/flipping will disrupt this arrangement of $R$ and $G$ relative to us. For example, consider the case $BW$. You can try to make this identical to the the $WB$ case, but notice that to get the $WB$ case we also need $R$ down and $G$ facing us. But then that was what we started with and we get the $BW$ back. So these two cases are surely different.

$2.$ We don’t care about the order of colours. The only thing that matters is we can take *any* such tetrahedron and orient it such that $R$ is facing downward and $G$ is facing towards us. And then there’s only two possibilities for the left and right faces: $BW$ or $WB$ which we have alreay accounted for. It’s safe to say there are only two arrangements using all four colors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get it now.